# Parameter conversion error cannot be output and parsing normally

Tags: python

I designed a program to determine whether a number is equal to a common multiple
Among them, the common multiple has the following conditions

```
(1) A multiple of 2, which is also a multiple of 11
(2) Not divisible by 5, nor divisible by 7

But an error message occurred after running my program
  if nus%2==0 and nus%11==0 and nus%5!=0 and nus%7!=0:
  not all arguments converted during string formatting

The normal execution result I hope is:
enter
Enter a positive integer: 22
22 is the new common multiple?: Yes
```

My code:

```
nus=input("Enter a positive integer:")
if nus%2==0 and nus%11==0 and nus%5!=0 and nus%7!=0:
     print(str(nus),"is the new common multiple?","Yes")
else:
     print(str(nus),"is the new common multiple?","No")
```

Comment: input returns a string. You'd want to convert that string into an int first.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
nus= int(input("Enter a positive integer:"))
```

as input returns value in string